# DbContext Ensure Created not working in .NET 8

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Hi recently I have switched from .NET Core 3 to .NET 8 and there I can't use the

```
dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated
```

Visual Studio 2022 with .NET version 8 does not have a startup file anymore.

I have tried to add the code in the program file but I am getting error. I don't know ho to access the EnsureCreated method in program.cs file.

Comment: `Startup` went away in .NET 6. Execution always started in `Main` anyway, not `Startup`. . The configuration is now performed in `Main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 8 we don't have a startup class. We only have a `Program.cs` file where we can add the register the services and there we can also add the Database `EnsureCreated` method.

All you need to do is go to the `Program.cs` class and before  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`
Add this code

```cs
using(var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope())
{
   var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiDbContext>();
   dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```